Discord role bot giving role when another is removed
I'm curious if it's possible to create a discord bot that manages roles with slash commands (/addrole, /removerole, etc.) and when the /removerole is used, it gives the member (whom the role's been removed) another role thats temporay (it stays on for a set amount of time, then gets removed automatically). I'm not very into discord.js so I'm curious if it's possible.
Expected use:
/addrole <role> <user> -> gives the specified role
/removerole <role> <user>  -> removes the specified role, and gives a temporary role for 7 days.

Seems possible, but if you don't want to make things complicated, you need to keep the server open until the bot removes that role or the role will stay (Unless you add something like a date for the removal of the role, but this might make things complicated):
Here is a little demonstration of what a temporary role might look like:


if (commandName === 'addrole') {
        let role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === interaction.options.getString('role'));
        let member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.options.getUser('user').id);
        await member.roles.add(role);
        await interaction.reply(`Role ${role.name} added to ${member.user.tag}`); //This is to announce the role adding part
    } else if (commandName === 'removerole') {
        let role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === interaction.options.getString('role'));
        let member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.options.getUser('user').id);
        await member.roles.remove(role); //This removes the first role
        let tempRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Temporary"); //And this gives the temporary role
        await member.roles.add(tempRole);
        await interaction.reply(`Role ${role.name} removed from ${member.user.tag} and temporary role added`); //This is to announce the role removing part
        setTimeout(async () => {
            await member.roles.remove(tempRole); //This sets time for the role removal.
        }, 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // This means seven days (We multiplied miliseconds to get to days)



But I might be wrong about some of the codes given since there has been a change in discord.js and I took this code from my old discord bot.
